# Write line if matches text

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to take a wordlist and for each keyword in the wordlist I want to search if it is on a line in a separate file. If the keyword is in a line, I want to write that line. The problem I am having is that my code is writing each and every line and not just the lines that have a keyword. Here's what I have:

```
import csv

open_output = open('list.csv','wb')
output_file = csv.writer(open_output)

searchedfile = open("searchedfile.csv",'rb')
read_file = csv.reader(searchedfile)

f = open('wordlist.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
words = []
for row in csv_f:
    item = row[0]
    words.append(item)

for line in read_file:
    if any(word in line[5] for word in words):
        output_file2.writerow([line[5]])
```

Comment: can you check that you don't have any empty strings in your `words` list? and if there's a word like `a`, then it will match any string containing `a`. Maybe you want to do:  `any(word == line[5] for word in words)` (exact match, not substring match). Sample data would be appreciated here. and fix indentation plz.

Comment: Switching to '==' worked very well. Thanks!